Some exercises about branches
I'm having difficulty with the following questions.
I'm also having trouble understanding how to work with branches and branch cuts - it's not very intuitive to me what's going on. I hope to recieve some tips...

let $ f $ be a holomorhpic function near $0$ such that $ f(0) = 0, f'(0) \neq 0 $. I need to prove that there exists some $g$, such that $ f(z^{2022}) = (g(z))^{2022} $.

I know that I can write $ f(z) = z h(z) $, for some holomorhpic function $h$. There was also a hint - defining $g(z) = (h(z))^{\frac{1}{2022}} $. However, why can we do that? and how does that help us, if still $ f(z) = z g^{2022} $?
